# Can I sort my sites using their Title inside my content search web part

Tags: development, search, content-search-web-part

I have a content search web part inside my sharepoint 2013 on premises site. The content search web part will show all the sub sites I have inside a site collection .. now everything is working well.. but the problem is that I am unable to sort the sub sites by their Title,, as the sort list inside the content search web part does not contain the Title.. so can any advice on this please??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of a site (the one present on (`/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx` page) resides in a crawled property called `ows_SiteName`.

You should map it to a `RefinableStringxx` managed property(see below screen grab) and then click OK.

To do that, go to your  `Central admin > Manage service applications > Search service application > Search Schema (under queries and results)`

[image]

Once the mapping is done, do a full crawl of the data source.

After that, you will be able to sort the results based on the site's title property.

You probably can also use another search mapped property called "SiteTitle", no need to create any extra refinableString then ;)

Comment: @Gautm thanks for the help and the great explanation.. but i am wondering why sharepoint did not do this mapping out of the box? as it do for many other built-in managed properties?

Comment: Well not sure why, but I guess the powers that be at Microsoft left it to the users/developers to do stuff they seem fit. Not everyone wants to sort based on site title, but if you want to do then the platform supports it !!!

Comment: unfortunately i followed your steps and then i tried to sort using RefinableStringxx Ascending where i will get the correct order for the first items only, where i got the sites with titles starting with A, then B, then C,the D, and so on.  but at the end of the search result i will get incorrect results.. here is  sample of the order which i got `Architecture >> Benchmark Electronic Design  >> ...... >> Software and Systems Engineering>> Windows 7 Migration Investigation>>Enhanced Communication in C++ >> Supervised In-traning`

Comment: ..so `Windows 7 Migration Investigation` is being shown before `Enhanced Communication in C++` !!

Comment: can u please advice on the above comments?

Comment: no idea why its behaving this way mate :(

Comment: no i check this again an the sort is working well !!! although when i test this i did a full crawl..

Answer (score 4):

You can map title to one of the RefinableString, crawl, and sort by that RefinableString

**UPDATE**

Go to **Central admin > Manage service applications > Search service application > Search Schema (under queries and results)**

Find one **RefinableString** (for ex RefinableString00,RefinableString01...), **edit property** and add one of titles.

You can add **ows_SiteName** or one of the Title managed property (for ex. **Basic:displayTitle**).
[image]

After that you have to **recrawl (full crawl)**.

Then **edit your wp** and **add sorting** by RefinableString00 
[image]

**SORTING**

Not so many predefined managed properties are sortable, maybe because MS implemented FAST Search with default sortable properties in SP2013.

You could also edit **SiteTitle** (ows_SiteName managed property) on **CA > Manage service applications > Search service application > Search Schema**.

Change **sortable** to **Yes-active** and **recrawl**.

**On SPO you can't do that**, only map to Refinable managed property

---

[Link](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/08/01/guide-to-the-search-schema-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Sorting has always been a big deal and highly requested feature in previous versions of SharePoint.  You really couldn’t sort by many criteria at all without writing custom code.  In SharePoint 2010, FAST Search for SharePoint added sorting capabilities but many people didn’t care to pay for it.  Well, now sorting is a first class feature in SharePoint 2013.  You can mark managed properties as sortable now and then use them in the search results web part.  Note, that you can only do this for properties at the Service Application level.

---

**EDIT 2**

You could create new **Result Source** which would override your sorting on wp.

Go to **Site settings>Site Collection Administration>Manage Result Sources**
**Create new**, give it name like **Sort Site Title**, under Query Transform **Launch Query Builder** and add sorting to your RefinableStringXX ASC.

Edit your **CSWP (Content Search Web Part)** and select your new **result source under Select a query**

[link](https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/stories/insights/2014/why-are-my-sort-orders-not-working-in-my-sharepoint-2013-search-results-web-part)

Comment: can you please provide more info about this? thanks

Comment: can you please advice more on this?

Comment: see my update or @gautam-sheth answer

Comment: thanks for the great reply and explanation.. but do u know the reason why this is not being done by defualt .. i mean sharepoint comes with predefined managed properties that are mapped to the crawl properties.. but in the `ows_SiteName` is there a performance or other reason why we need to map the `ows_SiteName` manually ?

Comment: See updated answer under SORTING

Comment: unfortunately i followed your steps and then i tried to sort using RefinableStringxx Ascending where i will get the correct order for the first items only, where i got the sites with titles starting with A, then B, then C,the D, and so on.  but at the end of the search result i will get incorrect results.. here is  sample of the order which i got `Architecture >> Benchmark Electronic Design  >> ...... >> Software and Systems Engineering>> Windows 7 Migration Investigation>>Enhanced Communication in C++ >> Supervised In-traning`

Comment: ..so `Windows 7 Migration Investigation` is being shown before `Enhanced Communication in C++` !! i thought when sorting ascending by site name i will get the sort in alphabetical order ..so sites starting with `W` will always appear after sites starting with `E`. but not sure what is going on ?

Comment: see updated answer under EDIT 2

Comment: but is it reasonable to create a new Result Source just to solve the sort issue on a webpart?... and i have a feeling since this did not work inside the default Result Source then this might not work inside the new Result Source as well.

Comment: no i check this again today an the sort is working well !!! although when i test this i did a full crawl..